# Priority Queue remove function not working

Tags: java

for this class, remove function of priority queue is not working properly
when implementing dijkstra's Algo. This is the class I created to 
sort elements in Priority Queue.Though the priority queue is removing
the min element correctly,it's  remove(object o) method is not 
removing the elements properly

```
public class IntegerArray implements Comparable<IntegerArray> {

public double[] a;

IntegerArray(double x,double y){

    a= new double[2];
    a[0]=x;
    a[1]=y;

}

public boolean equals(IntegerArray x){
    if(this.a[0]==x.a[0] & this.a[1] ==x.a[1]){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

public int compareTo(IntegerArray x){
    if(this.a[1] > x.a[1]){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(this.a[1] < x.a[1]){
        return -1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

///////this is the code for Dijsktra's algorithm where  priority queue is used

```
for (int i = 0; i < graph.get((int) node).size(); i++) {
  alt = (int) (dist[(int) node] + graph.get((int)      node).get(i).weight);
   if (alt < dist[ graph.get((int) node).get(i).vertex]) {
     temp1.a[0]=graph.get(node).get(i).vertex;
     temp1.a[1]=dist[graph.get(node).get(i).vertex];
     System.out.println("temp1" +" "+ temp1.a[0]+ " "+ temp1.a[1]);
     Q.remove(temp1);   //it is not removing though the object   instance is present in the queue
    dist[graph.get(node).get(i).vertex] = alt;
   pred[graph.get(node).get(i).vertex] = node;
   temp1.a[1]=dist[graph.get(node).get(i).vertex]; 
   System.out.println("temp1" +" "+ temp1.a[0]+ " "+ temp1.a[1]);
   Q.add(temp1);

}
```

Comment: you need to override `int hashCode()` function as well

Comment: Can you paste what the output you see on console when you run the program and what elements are there in your Queue? @parakmiakos i dont think hashcode would help here i.e. not used by PriorityQueue

Comment: he is creating (as far as I see) a new object `temp1`, and then invoking `remove(temp1)`. I think he needs to override hashCode, because he is basically asking to remove from the queue an object with the same values as another, not the same reference.

Comment: It prints that element is present in the queue,but it returns false when Q.remove(temp1) is called

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My mistake is I am passing the reference of the duplicate object i.e,temp1 rather than the reference of the original object.

Comment: True. That's the root cause of your mistake. But take a look at the other answers to understand why it happens and what is the right way of going about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `equals` is incorrect. The correct method has signature `public boolean equals(Object o)`, whereas yours has `public boolean equals(IntegerArray x)` (the type of the argument being different, the methods are distinct).

In `PriorityQueue.remove`, it is the `equals(Object)` that is called, and because you do not define it, the default implementation is called (comparison by identity).

Try this instead:

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
    IntegerArray x = (IntegerArray)o;
    return this.a[0] == x.a[0] && this.a[1] == x.a[1];
}
```

[Update] code redundancy reduced.

Comment: though the remove function is returning true,It is not  always removing the specified element  and instead removing the first one

Comment: If it returns true, it means it removed _something_. Did you add the same element twice? Can you print all values to see what exactly changed?

Comment: it  is removing the min element present in the queue

Comment: You should also create fresh instances of IntegerArray when you add them to the `PriorityQueue`. In your code, you reuse `temp1`, which seems to be the only instance you add.